# Is there any way to get error log when my app close unexpectedly?

Tags: android

I had wrote a app and upload it to google play

It works fine when testing but close unexpectedly when someone using it

I have no idea why it close unexpectedly

Is there any way to output error log to a file when my app close unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides a crash reporting api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions which allows you to gather information on both caught and uncaught exceptions.  There is also ACRA which is a third party tool, however you need to be very careful that when doing automated crash reporting you do not inadvertently include PII in the reports.

Comment: Hello,thanks for your answer,it helps alot,I can get the exception now.
One more quesion,I can't get the line number where the exception thrown ,I had tried exception.getStackTrace() but not like CaughtException can find where it thrown

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the answer to that.  You might pose a new question to StackOverflow with the code you are using and asking how to get the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using ACRA + HockeyApp with a great success. ACRA is a very versatile and robust tool which tracks not only stack traces, but also logs and device information.

HockeyApp serves as backend for processing ACRA's reports. Native HockeyApp's SDK does not allow to collect that much information -- so they do a good job in conjunction, ACRA for listening to exceptions within the app, and HockeyApp as report browser and alert manager.

This library helps a lot to make ACRA and HockeyApp work together: https://github.com/antoche/android-debug